# fetch data from multiple subnode in firebase using swift?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I want to fetch data from multiple subnodes? I am able to fetch from the first subnode, but unable to get the next subnode level. I need only the account section from the firebase

I used this function to fetch the first subnode.

```
func compareAccount() {
        REF_DRIVERS.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
            print(snapshot)
        }
    }
```

---

```
Snap (drivers) {
    9AyIYcizavM03ArvmQH1e3xQ7rD3 =     {
        account = Default;
        driverIsOnTrip = 0;
        isPickupModeEnabled = 0;
        provider = Firebase;
        userIsDriver = 1;
    };
    FCuTwkhtrbdBTx7akQI4NL49K5p1 =     {
        account = Default;
        coordinate =         {
            0 = "37.33233141";
            1 = "-122.0312186";
        };
        driverIsOnTrip = 0;
        isPickupModeEnabled = 0;
        provider = Firebase;
        userIsDriver = 1;
    };
    ML2Sxz6l78ZIZ0mO327nGmh0YkP2 =     {
        account = Default;
        driverIsOnTrip = 0;
        isPickupModeEnabled = 0;
        provider = Firebase;
        userIsDriver = 1;
    };
}

func compareAccount() {
        REF_DRIVERS.child("account").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
            print(snapshot)
        }
    }
```

When I try to print out only the account.
It prints this result

Snap (account)

Answer (score 1):

When you listen to a node, you get a snapshot with all data from that node. If that snapshot contains children for which you don't know the key (the driver IDs in your case), you can loop over all [child nodes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DataSnapshot#children). If you do know the key of a child node (as for example the `account` property), you can use [`childSnapshot(forPath:)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DataSnapshot#childsnapshotforpath) to get that node.

So by combining these, you can loop over your drivers and look up their properties by name:

```
REF_DRIVERS.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
    for case let driverSnapshot as DataSnapshot in snapshot.children {
       print(driverSnapshot.key)
       print(driverSnapshot.childSnapshot(forPath:"account").value)
    }
}
```